# Showing Children of page by name

Tags: wp-query

I have a page like this

```
phyiscs
---mechanics
---statics
---Universe

chemistry
---Reaction
---Equilibrium

biology
---Human body
---Polination
```

I want to display the chilren of page physics,chemistry , biology like this

```
<div class="phy-child">
   <h1>Mechanics</h1>
   <h1>statics</h1>
   <h1>Universe</h1>
</div>

<div class="chem-child">
   <h1>Reaction</h1>
   <h1>Equilibrium</h1>
</div>
```

and so for biology

I tried using wordpress query  but don't know where should i insert physics etc..

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'depth'          =>  2,
    'sort_column'  => 'post_name',
    'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'orderby'        => 'menu_order'
 );


$parent = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $parent->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php while ( $parent->have_posts() ) : $parent->the_post(); ?>

        <div id="parent-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="parent-page">

            <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

        </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Is it possible to do ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to pur div container before while loop.
Here you go. Here is the modified code and container will have parent page slug class.

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'depth'          =>  2,
    'sort_column'  => 'post_name',
    'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'orderby'        => 'menu_order'
 );


$parent = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $parent->have_posts() ) : ?>

  <div id="parent-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="<?php echo $post->post_name; ?>-page">

    <?php while ( $parent->have_posts() ) : $parent->the_post(); ?>

        <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

  </div>

<?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Hey I want to display it in archives page like that . But where do i show the children post using title of parents page like chemistry etc.

Comment: Not quite sure what exactly do you want. You said, need to show children of page. Please explain more.

Comment: Yes i want to show children of a page but on archives-notes.php ...I want to show children of physics using the name phyiscs .